# Should we delete the [homework] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup-request

The [homework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag is a meta-tag, which is [explicitly discouraged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homework).  Should we delete the homework tag from all questions?  Although a question may be about homework, there's nothing useful gained by tagging a question "homework".

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it should be removed.

It adds nothing.

From the existing questions, see if they can't be closed as too broad or just off topic before anything else.

If they're otherwise good, then edit as necessary and remove the tag while you're at it.

Answer (score -6):

**No**

[homework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homework) is one of the few meta tags still allowed since we welcome homework question on the Trilogy.

More on [homework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homework) on MSO: [Is [homework] an exception to the no-meta-tag rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception-to-the-no-meta-tag-rule)

More on the homework topic on MSO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I'm 100% for homework questions being asked, it's just that I don't think [homework] adds anything useful, and it can be used as a pejorative tag. But, if that's the consensus, then okay.

Comment: @Stephen - I agree with you. The homework tag adds nothing